# Specify Polygon lat/lon for defining Bounds in Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

As part of a project I am developing a web application which is required to extract POI information using Google Places API. Further, application is also required to filter the above extracted POI's based on user defined SPATIAL layers.

Ex: I have country boundary layer in Map Info format. I am required to filter out ATM's for a  country (country would be selected by the user).

I have successfully overlayed the user defined spatial data onto google Maps but I am not able to extract features which are intersecting the country boundary layer selected by the user.
Is there a way in which I can define a polygon to construct the bounds object while calling the places service??